# error: no such file or directory: Generics/Basic extensions/Swift/StringExtension.swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am building an iPhone project in XCode and get the following error:

:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Generics/Basic extensions/Swift/StringExtension.swift'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

The project.pbxproj file thinks it should be here:
../../../../Generics/Basic extensions/Swift/StringExtension.swift

There are other Swift extensions directly in the project folder, but I seem to be missing the basic extensions. I have XCode 6.4 with Swift 1.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out they were custom Swift Extensions and I was able to get them from the creator (of the project).